# A function that is not in $L_2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}=\{r_1,r_2,\ldots\}$ and $\phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ if $x\in (0,1)$, and $\phi(x)=0$ if $x\notin{(0,1)}$.

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, where $a_n>0$ and let $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\phi(x-r_n)$.

I want to prove that $f^2$ is not Lebesgue integrable in $(a,b)$, where $a<b$.

Any hint to show that $\displaystyle\int_{(a,b)}f^2=+\infty$?

Thanks :)

Comment: $f \geq a_1 \phi(x - r_1) \geq 0$. it suffices to show that this part is not in $L^2$, can you do that? can you show that $\phi$ itself is not in $L^2$?

Comment: @mm-aops It's almost enough - that shows that $\phi$ is not in $L^2(a,b)$ for any interval $(a, b)$ containing $r_1$. Now the density of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ is necessary to extend this result to *any* open interval.

Comment: right, thanks, I didn't notice the part saying you have to prove it on every open interval, but as you said that doesn't change a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothesis that $\sum a_n$ converges is unnecessary.
Also, the series for $f$ may
diverge at points,
but you can just assume that at those points $f(x) = \infty$.

I can't think of a better way than the hint expressed in the comments.
Pick any interval $(a,b)$, and let $r_k$ be a rational number in it.
(Why can we do this?)
Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ with $r_k + \epsilon < b$ and $\epsilon < 1$
(why?)
Then try showing that
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(x) \; dx
&\ge \int_a^b \left( a_k\phi(x - r_k) \right)^2 \; dx \\
&\ge a_k^2 \int_{r_k}^{r_k + \epsilon} \left[\phi(x - r_k)\right]^2 \; dx \\
&= a_k^2 \int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{x} \; dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you! Btw, you mean $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$, right?

Comment: @Sylas Ah yes, thanks for the catch.